# Accessing specific member of an ArrayList using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I have a table in a jsp page which shows the data fetched from a database via an ArrayList forwarded to the page. Each row of the table has a radio button corressponding to it. Now, I would like to access the elements in the row (the ArrayList's members on the selection of the corresponding radio button and then click of an 'edit' button)
Any thoughts as to how to achieve this would be very much appreciated. Here's my code for a bit intro.

```
<% 
   ArrayList<requestbean> reqjsp = new ArrayList<requestbean>();
   reqjsp = (ArrayList<requestbean>) (request.getAttribute("reqdb"));
%>

<script type ="text/javascript">
   function x() {
      var ele = document.getElementsByName('reqradio');
      var i = ele.length;
      for ( var j = 0; j < i; j++ ) {
         if ( ele[j].checked ) {
             document.getElementById("edireq").disabled = false;
             alert('request ' + ( j + 1 ) + ' selected');
             //Here is where the functionality is desired to access reqjsp.get(j)
        }      
     }
  }
</script> 
<input type="button" name="edireq" id="edireq" onclick="x()" value="Edit Request">
```

These are a few columns in my table.

```
<%
 for ( int i = 0; i < reqjsp.size(); i++ ) {
%>
  <tr> 
    <td> <input type="radio" name="reqradio" id="req<%=(i+1) %>"></td> 
    <td><%= reqjsp.get(i).getRequestid() %></td>            
    <td><%= reqjsp.get(i).getRequestor() %></td>  
    <td><%= reqjsp.get(i).getApprover() %></td>              
  </tr> 
<%} %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could generate a JavaScript array with JSP code and then access this generated variable in your JavaScript. But you would not be able to change anything in the underlying Java object this way:

```
<script type ="text/javascript">
<% 
   ArrayList<requestbean> reqjsp = new ArrayList<requestbean>();
   reqjsp = (ArrayList<requestbean>) (request.getAttribute("reqdb"));
%>
var myJsArray = new Array();
<%
   for ( int i = 0; i < reqjsp.size(); i++ ) {
%>
myJsArray.push('<%= reqjsp.get(i) %>');
<%
   }
%>

// JavaScript code to access the myJsArray array

</script>
```

The JSP code will generate this kind of code:

```
<script type ="text/javascript">
var myJsArray = new Array();
myJsArray.push('value1');
myJsArray.push('value2');
myJsArray.push('value3');

// JavaScript code to access the myJsArray array

</script>
```